# Can I add functionality to this number incrementor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am still learning JavaScript so I wanted to use this as an added opportunity to learn more.
Currently, the code is written in only HTML & CSS. Where I need help is in making this work with JavaScript.

I saw a number incrementor/decrementor (like the one used to include more items or less into a shopping cart), and I was trying to imitate this cool stuff. But, I am not very sure how to code the Vanilla JS to make it work.

There are 5 slides, I just want the plus and minus buttons to work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #888888;
  display: grid;
}

div.body {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

div.body div.inner {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  width: fit-content;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

div.body div.inner div.num_slides {
  background-color: #409bd0;
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
  width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Yu Gothic UI';
}

div.body div.inner div.num_slides div.num {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: inherit;
  min-width: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

div.body div.inner div.btn {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #333333;
}

div.body div.inner div.btn:hover {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.body div.inner div.btn.deactivated {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="btn deactivated" id="minus">
      <span>&minus;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="num_slides">
      <div class="num">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn" id="plus">
      <span>&plus;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me out, guys. Thank You!

Comment: If you want to increment the numbers, then why did you make _5_ `div.num`?
Do you expect animation of slide up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a script to listen to click Events and then execute the script. For that, you can use `addEventListener`.

Then you need a variable like `index` to act as a counter. If you click on `minus` the counter needs to be lowered by 1 with `variable--` or in the other case raised with `variable++`.

After that, you change the content of the button with `textContent` and just let it pull the counter variable as content.

Last but not least, you need to prevent the `minus`-button to work if it reached 1. You can do this CSS-wise by adding `pointer-events: none` to the `deactivated` class

```js
var buttonMinus = document.querySelector('#minus'),
    buttonPlus = document.querySelector('#plus'),
    button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    buttonText = document.querySelector('.num');
var index = 1; //variable acting as counter

/* eventListener to listen if you clicked on the minus button */
buttonMinus.addEventListener('click', function() {
  index--; //lowers the counter by 1
  updateText(); //runs next fucntion
})

/* eventListener to listen if you clicked on the plus button */
buttonPlus.addEventListener('click', function() {
  index++; //raises the counter by 1
  updateText(); //runs next function
})

/* function to updates the text */
function updateText() {
  buttonText.textContent = index; //updates the text
  /* adds / removes the deactivated class depending if the index is 1 or not */
  switch (index) {
    case 1:
      buttonMinus.classList.add('deactivated');
      break;
    case 100:
      buttonPlus.classList.add('deactivated');
      break;
    default:
      button.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('deactivated'));
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #888888;
  display: grid;
}

div.body {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

div.body div.inner {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  width: fit-content;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

div.body div.inner div.num_slides {
  background-color: #409bd0;
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
  width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Yu Gothic UI';
}

div.body div.inner div.num_slides div.num {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: inherit;
  min-width: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

div.body div.inner div.btn {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #333333;
}

div.body div.inner div.btn:hover {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.body div.inner div.btn.deactivated {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="btn deactivated" id="minus">
      <span>&minus;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="num_slides">
      <div class="num">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn" id="plus">
      <span>&plus;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW! An infinite incrementor! EXACTLY WHAT I WAS TALKING ABOUT...

Comment: Wait, it seems to go below 0. can it end at zero? I've been incrementing until I cannot see the buttons anymore

Comment: nope try again, I fixed that already CSS wise

Comment: Okay, I think I'm done incrementing. Could you set a limit to 100?

Comment: It's simple, set an if condition so if the value is 0 disable the minus button, and when the value is 100 disable the plus button...

Comment: I edited the snippet and included a `switch`-case that will now listen to the index and disable the correct button at 1 or 100 (it's more efficient than multiple `if`-statements). @AgrimSingh you are not wrong but on a technical level, it would be inefficient. you need at least 3 `if`-conditions. `if (index = 1)` + `if (index > 1 && index < 100)` + `if (index = 100)` -> which leads to my before mentioned `switch`-statement which does that faster and with requiring less computing resources.

Comment: Hmm. So switch is better than if?

Comment: @MattDon yes in nearly all cases. The thing is, that `switch`-statements are optimized and are a single statement over then multiple `if`-statements. The compiler knows all cases of a `switch`-statement straight away while it does not for `if`-statements. All `if`-statements are run 1-by-1 and checked if the statement is true. For the `switch`-statement the statement is run too and instantly knows which case is true and the rest ignored.

Comment: @tacoshy is right, the `switch` statement is much better than `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any slides. You just need to [select your button elements](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) one by one, [add listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) to them and change [textContent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp) of the "counter" element when one of the buttons is clicked